# Count unique values in column based on another column (Microsoft Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, vba, office-2013

For a project, I'm creating an Excel macro to count unique column values based on another column value. Here is a basic example of the macro I'm trying to create:

### Data

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | x |
| a | y |
| b | z |
| b | z |

### Macro

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim Param As String
    Param = "a"
    MsgBox UniqueValues(Param)
End Sub

Function UniqueValues(Param As String) As String
    Dim EvaluateString As String
    EvaluateString = "=SUM(--(LEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=" & """" & Param & """" & ","""")))>0))"
    UniqueValues = Evaluate(EvaluateString)
End Function
```

### Expectation

The expectation is that for `Param = "a"` the function returns `2` and for `Param = "b"` it returns `1`.

### Issue

Even though function works perfpectly in Excel for Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise, the project requires me to use Excel for Microsoft Office Standard 2013. This version doesn't support the use of the `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions used in `EvaluateString`.

I want to understand if there's a simple way to count the unique values in a column based on a value in another column in Excel for Microsoft Office Standard 2013. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the array formula

`=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$5="a",1/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$5,"a",$B$1:$B$5,$B$1:$B$5)),0)`

After entering the formula, instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you need to press <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

In VBA, the above formula can be used as shown below

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim Param As String
    Param = "b"
    
    MsgBox "The count for " & Param & " is " & UniqueValues(Param)
End Sub

Function UniqueValues(Param As String) As String
    Dim EvaluateString As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    'SUM(IF(Sheet1!A1:A5="a",1/COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A1:A5,"a",Sheet1!B1:B5,Sheet1!B1:B5)),0)
    EvaluateString = "SUM(IF($A$1:$A$5=" & _
                     Chr(34) & Param & Chr(34) & _
                     ",1/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$5," & _
                     Chr(34) & Param & Chr(34) & _
                     ",$B$1:$B$5," & _
                     "$B$1:$B$5)),0)"
                     
    UniqueValues = ws.Evaluate(EvaluateString)
End Function
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping out. Your solution works perfectly. I have slightly modified your suggestion to make it work for my use case!

Comment: Glad it worked Frank :)

Comment: Side note: instead of prefixing *three* range addresses (of the *same* sheet) with textual insertions of `ws.Name & "'!"` it's possible to return a *sheet referenced evaluation* like `UniqueValues = ws.Evaluate(EvaluateString)`  as function result :-)

Comment: @T.M. Yes you are right. I always use `ws.Evaluate`. I am not sure what I was experimenting with and forgot to change it back. Let me fix that right now

Answer (score 0):

When your data are in "Sheet1", columns A and B, starting in row 1, you can use this macro (results in columns D and E):

```
Sub macro1()
Dim a As Integer, p As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer
a = 0: p = 0: x = 1: y = 1
With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Columns("d:e").ClearContents
Do Until x > .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
a = 1
Do While .Cells(x, 1) = .Cells(y, 1)
If .Cells(x, 2) <> .Cells(y, 2) Then a = a + 1
x = x + 1
Loop
p = p + 1
.Cells(p, 4) = .Cells(y, 1)
.Cells(p, 5) = a
y = x
Loop
End With
End Sub
```